# connecting to mysql db in azure linux vm with lamp stack

Tags: mysql, linux, azure

we are testing azure cloud platform for our future use, we saw digitalocean tutorials on how to install a lamp stack, everything seems find, but we are unable to fine, but we are unable to connect to database, we are using following details to connect

```
$host = "{our_url}.cloudapp.net:3306";
$user = "root";
$pass = "rootpassword";
$connection = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
if($connection)
{
     echo "Great";
}
else
{
     echo mysql_error();
}
// we are getting this error can't connect to MySQL server on '{our_url}.cloudapp.net' (111)
```

**things to mention**

1. we have three end points 22 for ssh, 3306 for MySQL, 80 for http
2. we are using same url that we created which we create while creating ubuntu vm

Comment: There are too many possible causes.... did you check where your SQL server can accept connections from? - how about basics: is it running?

Answer (score 0):

1) Don't use root account

2) Root account is locked to localhost access by default

3) Create a new user and grant permissions to your database

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON <mydatabase>.* TO '<myuser>'@'<myip>' IDENTIFIED BY '<mypassword>' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

4) If you still want to use root account

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '<rootpassword>' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

'%' means any ip. You have lock root access to a specific ip.